# "Could not load file or assembly" error when net462 app references a netstandard1.5 library. But why?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, .net-standard, .net-4.6.2

I am trying to figure out what I could be doing wrong in this sample project. I am getting an error when my `net462` application references a `netstandard1.5` library. The application has a dependency on `"System.Collections.Immutable": "1.3.0"`, which targets NetStandard 1.0 according to Nuget. The library depends on `"NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0"`.

Am I setting up either of these projects wrong? I would greatly appreciate any insight on this...

Here are their project.json :

app:

```
{
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "SomeLibrary": "1.0.0-*"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "net462": {
      "dependencies": {
        "System.Collections.Immutable": "1.3.0" 
      }
    }
  },
  "version": "1.0.0-*"
}
```

Library

```
{
  "buildOptions": {
    "allowUnsafe": true
  },
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.5": {
      "dependencies": {
        "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0"
      }
    }
  },
  "version": "1.0.0-*"
}
```

All the library has is this interface:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace SomeLibrary
{
    public interface SomeInterface
    {
        int GetValue(KeyValuePair<string, int> somePair);
    }
}
```

The app implements this interface and makes a call the concrete class:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var concreteObject = new ConcreteImplementation();
        var answer = concreteObject.GetValue(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("key", 33));
        Console.WriteLine(answer);
    }
}


class ConcreteImplementation : SomeInterface
{
    public int GetValue(KeyValuePair<string, int> somePair)
    {
        return somePair.Value;
    }
}
```

If I try to run the app, here is the error that I get:

`{"Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.":"System.Runtime, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"}`

Stack:  `at ErrorExample.Consumer..ctor()
   at ErrorExample.Program.Main(String[] args) in ..\ErrorExample\src\ErrorExample\Program.cs:line 11`

What am I missing here?
Thanks!

Comment: That says you cannot use `net462` with `netstandard1.5`. Try to use `net462` for your library.

Comment: I thought they were supposed to be compatible, as seen on the matrix in this article (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/standard/library), or maybe I am interpreting the matrix wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure about why this is happening, but using **`netstandard1.4`** as a TFM for your library project would resolve your issue. In other words, `project.json` of your library should look like that:

```
{
  "buildOptions": {
    "allowUnsafe": true
  },
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.4": { // <-- replace "netstandard1.5" with "netstandard1.4" or lower
      "dependencies": {
        "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0"
      }
    }
  },
  "version": "1.0.0-*"
}
```

And as a current general rule of thumb: avoid using `netstandard1.5` and `netstandard1.6`: use **`netstandard1.4`** and lower according to your requirements until you are explicitly forced to. Wait for release of `netstandard2.0`. You may read the details about it in the [MSDN blog artible about .NET Standard](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/09/26/introducing-net-standard/). And here's a [FAQ](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/docs/faq.md).

Comment: You are right: if I change it to netstandard1.4 things start working again. However, in my actual project I do not have control over the netstandard that is being implemented.

However, knowing that it works in 1.4 might be a hint of the underlying problem. Ultimately, I still want to know what is the fundamental problem here. Thanks!

Comment: I'd suggest you posting the issue at [Microsoft's coreclr repository](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr) then.

Comment: I got a very similar problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41535341/using-net-standard-1-5-lib-in-net-4-6-2-misses-system-runtime-4-1-0-0 any hint ?