# Cannot access types of .NET Standard Library

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2017, .net-4.6.2, .net-standard-1.5

I created in VS2017 two C# projects:

- .NET Standard 1.5 library
- .NET Framework 4.6.2 Console application. (implements Standard 1.5)

I added the reference to the library, but cannot access types from it.
Compiler just complains that it cannot find neither namespace nor class.

Moreover, Studio allows to start the application and then throws:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Runtime, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.'

So, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: 4.6.1 implements only .NET Standard 1.4 so I'm not sure you can reference 1.5 library.

Comment: @TóthTibor Sorry, mistyped.  4.6.2, not 4.6.1 Corrected my question.

Comment: Are these empty projects or do they have code?

Comment: @TóthTibor I just added a single class to the library.

Comment: It's really weird because I can reproduce your bug but after I tried to downgrade the versions to 1.4 and 4.6.1 it worked good. Then I upgrade to 1.5 and 4.6.2 and this is also worked which was bad before...

Comment: @TóthTibor Well, it started building solution without errors after restarting VS. Thow exception is still thrown.

Comment: I can't provide more help. It's a bug for me too (VS2017 RTM). :(

Comment: @TóthTibor Yep, found one more. It can hang on 'Build started...' =)

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the same problem but I posted [this on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/17014).

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to bring your Framework project down to net46.  That is what [the compatibility matrix](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/docs/versions.md) says.

Comment: @TóthTibor where do you read 4.6.1 implements .NET Standard 1.4?  Link in my comment above indicates 4.6 supports up to Standard 1.6.

Comment: @Sam He probably read it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/standard/library)

Comment: @Sam, assembly version mismatch is another possible cause, but as davidsh at GitHub commented, the assembly facade is also needed, which is covered by my answer.

Comment: already answered here (with some more details) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41535341/using-net-standard-1-5-lib-in-net-4-6-2-misses-system-runtime-4-1-0-0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add NETStandard.Library to your reference list of the traditional project. Then all related assemblies would appear in your output folder so that runtime exceptions won't occur. (If you do need anything more than .NET Standard Library, also add that package to this traditional project).

At this stage, it is a limitation we have to get used to. Ultimately Microsoft should find a better way to address it.

(Note that you might also need assembly redirection in app.config, if there are version number mismatch.)

Comment: The number of pulled packages is impressive =)